# Should headings divide space unequally and be close to the border?

Tags: typography, critique, borders, white-space, latex

This is a chapter heading of an `ebook` style of LaTeX, and it divides space unequally. Small phone screen doesn't mean it need to be close to the top border to make the reading flow rushy, does it?

[image]

Comment: You space typography primarily for readability. The 'emotional' level of the text is somewhat irrelevant above and beyond and mostly just comes down to personal opinion of the designer.

Comment: @DA01 do you have any recommendation for white spacing in text requiring thinking and has purpose to evoke emotions, like poem?

Comment: there are no hard and fast rules here. Do what you fell works best for the content.